# How can I update/refresh the view of a ListView after performing an action like a tap on a row

Tags: flutter, listview, setstate

I'm following the saved/favourite tutorial from Flutter website

code:

```
void _pushFavourites() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
        var tiles = _favourites.map((WordPair pair) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(pair.asCamelCase, style: _fontStyle),
            onTap: () {
              // ⬇︎ probably here I should update tiles, but I don't know how to do it
              setState(() {
                _favourites.remove(pair);
              });
            },
          );
        });
        final divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
          context: ctx,
          tiles: tiles,
        ).toList();

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Favourite Suggestions')),
          body: ListView(children: divided,)
        );
        
      })
    );
  }
```

The whole code is [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2#5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling `setState` of the parent route (the widget that has the function `_pushFavourites`)

create a separate stateful widget for this part of code and it should work:

```
var tiles = _favourites.map((WordPair pair) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(pair.asCamelCase, style: _fontStyle),
            onTap: () {
              // ⬇︎ probably here I should update tiles, but I don't know how to do it
              setState(() {
                _favourites.remove(pair);
              });
            },
          );
        });
        final divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
          context: ctx,
          tiles: tiles,
        ).toList();

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Favourite Suggestions')),
          body: ListView(children: divided,)
        );
```

Comment: Great it worked!
I'm quite new with Flutter, I got to better understand the logic behind the stateful widgets